# How to make a custom landing page in Laravel and how to apply routing?

Tags: laravel, routes

The "/" (index page as landing page) and "pages/home" (Home page) must be different in that the landing page must not have navigation and footer.

I have tried the redirect method which led both urls showing the same page.
I have also used the standard routing method which works partially. The only problem is I do not want to have the header and footer of the home page on the landing page.
Maybe, one way to achieve this is to use two different blade layout files. Like app.blade.php and landing.blade.php. But the problem again might be of routing between the landing page and home page as both are from two different layout files.

WEB/PHP

```
Route::redirect('/', '/home', 301);

Route::get('/home', 'PagesController@index');
```

CONTROLLERS/PagesController

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class PagesController extends Controller
{

public function index(){
    return view('pages.index');
}

public function home(){
  return view('pages.home');
}

}
```

app.blade.php

```
<body>
<div class="container"> 
    @include('inc.navbar')
    @yield('content')
    @include('inc.footer')
</div>
</body>
```

I expect a different page for landing but header and footer appears on the landing page as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can get rid of the controller entirely for this

```php
Route::view('/', 'pages.index');

Route::view('/home', 'pages.home');
```

Now if you go to visit the site `example.com` you'll see the landing page

And `example.com/home` shows the home page

Another solution would be to exclude the header and footer from the app layout if the request path is '/' i.e the landing page

```html
<body>
    <div class="container">
        @includeWhen(request()->path() != '/', 'inc.navbar')
        @yield('content')
        @includeWhen(request()->path() != '/', 'inc.footer')
    </div>
</body>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: example.com throws 404 error page.
example.com/landing directs to another page in the site example.com/contact

Comment: The rest of the pages are using a controller to handle page navigation

Comment: public function contacts(){
       return view('pages.contacts');
     }
This is the one of the lines in the controller and this is the one which has become the new landing page